# Node.js / Express - Rest Api Call Counter

Tags: rest, express

i have a little problem. at first i have not really a great experience with node...hope that will be better :-)

here is my task:

- for every call on :3000/api/newgame add +1 to the mongo scheme Game.counter

Here is my actually code:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var gameCounter   = new Schema({
    counter: [Number]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GameCounter', gameCounter);
```

This is my mongo definition.

And here ist my router.js file:

```
router.get('/newgame',function(req, res){


  GameCounter.find(function(err, games){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);

      var setGame = new GameCounter();
      setGame.counter = //and here i need to add +1
      setGame.save();

      res.json({ success: true, message: 'new game has counted', gamesplayed: games });
  });
});
```

Someone a little a help for me ? thanks :)

Comment: You don't add to a scheme (or model), you add to a document. So it is the idea that there will be one `GameCounter` document in the database, and its counter should be increased for each call to `/api/newgame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be something like this :

schema :

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var gameCounter   = new Schema({
    counter: Number
});
```

and node code :

```
router.get('/newgame', function(req, res) {

   GameCounter.update({}, {
      $inc: {
         counter: 1
      }
   }, {
      upsert: true
   }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
         cb(err);
         res.send(err);
      } else {
         res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'new game has counted',
            gamesplayed: games
         });
      }
   });

});
```

UPDATE:
in your code style you can do something like this :

```
router.get('/newgame', function(req, res) {

   GameCounter.findOne(function(err, games) {
      if (err) {
         res.send(err);
      } else if (games) {

         games.counter++;

         games.save((err, new_data) => {
            if (err) {
               res.send(err);
            } else {
               res.json({
                  success: true,
                  message: 'new game has counted',
                  gamesplayed: new_data.counter
               });
            }
         });
      }
   });    
});
```

Comment: I removed my comment to post a new one suggesting that `findOneAndUpdate()` is perhaps more appropriate :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the last example, as it will have concurrency issues (there's a bit of time between `findOne` and `save`, and in that time another request could just have updated the counter already).